# Why does assigning document.body affect subsequent access to it?

Tags: javascript

This code runs as I expect:

```js
let vw, vh
[vw, vh] = [document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight]
console.log(vw)
```

But this code doesn't.  Just the unused assignment seems to change the behavior.

```js
let vw, vh
const thebody = document.body  // what did I do wrong besides waste an assignment??
[vw, vh] = [document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight]
console.log(vw)
```

Weirder still, logging the body logs it, but causes an error on the next assignment...

```js
 let vw, vh
 const thebody = document.body
 console.log(thebody) // what did I do EXTRA wrong besides log something??
 [vw, vh] = [document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight]
 console.log(vw)
```

Comment: You're missing some semicolons

Comment: Ooh. I think I'm about to learn something, @Pointy.  I thought I could drop semicolons with impunity.  I must be wrong?

Comment: Yep :)  `console.log(thebody)` followed by a newline is still an "open" expression, so the `[ ]` on the following line is considered to be a property access.

Comment: Personally I don't like telling people what to do but I consider the proponents of "never bother with semicolons" to be misguided individuals.

Comment: One reason why it’s not a good reason to blindly and blithely drop semi colon because “you could do it”

Comment: This is a nice piece of code to illustrate how people confuse 'Javascript will TRY to make sense of code which omits semi-colons' with 'Javascript will always work out what you meant'. They are not ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For array destructuring assignment you need to include a semi colon before it...

```
const thebody = document.body; // Semicolon here
[vw, vh] = ...
```

... otherwise it is going to be interpreted as bracket notation of attempting to access a value in an object:

```
const thebody = document.body[vw, vh] = ...
```